# KeyCode using template reference variables

Tags: angular

I was going through Angular documentation. As per the doc, template reference variables should be preferred over $events as most of the times we won't need the entire payload.

Link: https://angular.io/guide/user-input

I have two questions here now:

1> Could we get keycode with the template reference variables. I am aware of specific key event filters (keyup.enter etc). But what if I want to listen to a specific key (eg: alphabet A) -- could it be achieved with a template reference variable.

2> Instead of passing the entire $event attribute, if I pass the value (to be used): $event.target.value -- does it nullify the use of template variables or should the template variables be still preferred.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation say that is preferible use template reference variable if you want to use a propertie of the "html tag".

A keypressed it's not a propertie of the .html, so the only way is use (keyup)="myfunction($event)".

If only want to check a key you can use (keydown.A) -"a"- or (keydown.shift.A) "A", other "modifiers are ['alt', 'control', 'meta', 'shift'] -you can combine all of them, e.g. (keydown.control.shift.A)-, see 
[the fonts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/platform-browser/src/dom/events/key_events.ts#L24)

Or read [this amazing article](https://netbasal.com/diy-keyboard-shortcuts-in-your-angular-application-4704734547a2) of Netanel Basal